# How to set long lines of computer output without breaking on spaces

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I am trying to set very long lines of computer output that have the form:

```
text(text, "this is text that may span several lines and that may have only one or two spaces in it, or perhaps none") = text
```

InDesign's paragraph formatter, of course, tries to break on the spaces, but I want to break at the paragraph width, no matter what. So, to use a more compact example, if the text I'm trying to set looks like "abcde fghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz", then:

```
[--paragraph width--]  ...what I want (break on width)
abcde fghij klmnopqrs
tuvwxyz

[--paragraph width--]  ...what I get (break on space)
abcde fghij
klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

How can I get InDesign to break at such a point that it considers "mid-word"?

Comment: Hi Cary, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I have tried creating a GREP style to use a "no break" character style upon the pattern ".{168}", but that results in an apparently infinitely long overset text problem. The number 168 is magic because my frame will hold 168 characters in the fixed-pitch font I'm using. I've tried smaller numbers, resulting in the same apparent outcome.